# How can I pass data back to ViewController from delegated class method in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

in ViewController, I initlize a class, `Location`, that is in Location.swift in order to use it's methods.

in `ViewDidLoad`, I call the first method in `Location` which setups up the location services (permissions, etc). Also in Location, are two delegated methods from CLLocationManagerDelegate.

ViewController looks like (simplified!):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
     var location = Location();
     override func viewDidLoad() {
          location.initLocation();
          //when updated data from delegated method, i want to get data to here, in order to output it in UI labels,etc
     }
}
```

Location.swift looks like (simplified!):

```
import CoreLocation

class Location: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate{
      func initLocation(){
         ........
      }

      @objc func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading){
            //i want to send  newHeading data to viewController here
      }

}
```

I  can easily get data back from `initLocation()`, as I call and define the method myself. But what if i need to get data from the `locationManager` method, which is not called by me?

Do ask if you have any questions. I hope I have explained adequately!

Cheers

Comment: Do you need the newHeading value everytime it updates or do you want to just be able to call this class to get the newHeading most recent value?

Comment: You should use... delegation! Create a protocol, for example `LocationDelegate`, and implement it by your `ViewController`.

Comment: @KotaBear233 everytime it updates :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a new delegate for Location, like:

ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, LocationDeleate {

    var location = Location()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

       location.deleagte = self
       //location.initLocation()
   }

   func initLocation() {

       //when updated data from delegated method, i want to get data to here, in order to output it in UI labels,etc
   }
}
```

Then create a new protocol swift file:

LocationProtocol.swift

```
protocol LocationProtocol : class {
    func initLocation()
}
```

Location.swift

```
import CoreLocation

class Location: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate{

    weak var delegate : LocationDelegate?

    @objc func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading){

        // send notification to parent view controller
        delegate?.initLocation()
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. What does it mean when u put the class keyword after the protocol definition name?

Comment: This marks the protocol as only usable by classes, if you remove the ": class" you will get this error on your delegate object: "'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not 'LocationProtocol'".